# How to create a Microsoft Access report with a date range

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

If this is not the forum to ask this question, please direct me to the correct one.

I am trying to learn Micosoft Access 2013 programming. I am trying to create a report on a form to display the table info based on a user defined range of the creation date. How would I go about doing this? Is the creation date stored automatically, available for retrieval?

Comment: creation date of what ? record ? table ? the earth ?

Comment: creation date of the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Access does not automatically store the creation date of a record. However, you can accomplish that by adding a `Date/Time` field named [RecordCreated] (or whatever) to the table and setting its `Default Value` to `Now()`. That won't add a timestamp to existing records, but new records will automatically have their creation date (and time) recorded.